# How to get connected device count in hotspot(AP) programmatically [Android]

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-networking

Am working on a application which need to show the hotspot details including the number of device connected to the hotspot

I tried this but not worked ,

```
private int countNumMac()
    {
        int macCount =0;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
            String line;

            System.out.println(br.toString());
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] splitted = line.split(" +");
                System.out.println("splitted :"+splitted);

                if (splitted != null && splitted.length >= 4) {
                    // Basic sanity check
                    String mac = splitted[3];
                    if (mac.matches("..:..:..:..:..:..")) {
                        macCount++;
                    } 
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(macCount == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return macCount-1; 
    }
```

Is there any other method to count the number of device connected to hotspot..

Answer (score 0):

The code you entered needs root access
Take a look at this library. I hope it solves your problem
https://github.com/nickrussler/Android-Wifi-Hotspot-Manager-Class

Answer (score 0):

You do not need root access to accomplish what you are trying to do.

As far as counting connected devices you can easily just ping each possible host on the subnet and then count them.

Here is an open-source project that may give you some stepping stones along your journey to your new app :)
https://github.com/VREMSoftwareDevelopment/WiFiAnalyzer